# ImageResizer AzureReader2 redirectToBlobIfUnmodified not working

Tags: azure-blob-storage, imageresizer

I am using Image Resizer's AzureReader2 and everything is working fine except when I try to get the unmodified image it redirects to my blob storage.

If i request a modified image it returns the correct url:

```
http://localhost:57474/azure/images/test/githubavatar.jpg?width=200&height=600
```

But requests for the unmodified image redirect to blob storage

```
http:localhost:57474/azure/images/test.jpg
```

but instead it is redirecting to blob storage:

```
https://{storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/images/test/test.jpg
```

I have redirectToBlobIfUnmodified set to false but it doesn't do anything

```
<resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
      <add name="AzureReader2"
            redirectToBlobIfUnmodified="false"
            connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={storageAccountName};AccountKey={storageAccountKey}"
            endpoint="https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/"
           />
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
```

Comment: Are you using V4? This configuration attribute is new, and doesn't exist in v3.

Comment: I'm using the latest version on nuget 3.4.3. Is there are way to not redirect to blob storage in v3?

Comment: No, you'll need to use v4, which is still [in the nightly feed](https://www.myget.org/F/imazen-nightlies/).

Comment: Updated to version 4 of image Resizer and AzureReader2 and updated Azure storage to 4 and Azure Configuration to 3, but now I am getting "Source Not Found" BlobProviderBase.cs not found. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post a [gist](https://gist.github.com) of the new error?

Comment: Taking too much time, I rolled back to version 3 and I'm just going to have it redirect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: We can't help you, nor improve the product, without exception details.

Comment: If you expect a resolution within 75 minutes you should consider a support contract instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with ImageResizer AzureReader2 but I did a little research on there [docs](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/azurereader2).

[image]

From what I understand, if you set the endpoint to localhost rather than blob storage, then the server should perform redirects to localhost when you don't need to modify the blob.

Comment: Yep you're understanding it right I should probably just delete the question since its solved with the new version I was just using an older version that didn't have that feature now that I've upgraded it works fine.